# Electron/NodeJS and multi-threaded python application inter process communication

Tags: python, node.js, electron, ipc

I am building an Electron app that has to communicate with a multi-threaded python application. My initial solution was to use `spawn` in the `child_process` package to spawn a ChildProcess and use stdio to communicate back and forth.

This is proving to be a lot harder than I had expected and I am not able to get a response from the python program in Electron. You can see the nodeJS code below. I am trying to use a virtual environment for python. And, the same command that I am trying to run with spawn works when used in the terminal.

I have tried adding listeners on many different events, but this is code that I found in a lot of tutorials.

```
export class PythonProcess {
  private process: ChildProcess;
  constructor() {
    console.log(`${path.resolve(__dirname, 'exec/venv/bin/python')}`);
    console.log(`${path.resolve(__dirname, 'exec/init.py')}`);

    this.process = spawn(
      `${path.resolve(__dirname, 'exec/venv/bin/python')}`,
      [`${path.resolve(__dirname, 'exec/init.py')}`, '-local']
    );
    this.process.on('exit', this.exitHandler);

    this.process.stdout?.on('data', this.recieve);
    this.process.stdout?.on('error', this.recieve);
  }

  send(cmd: Number) {
    this.process.stdin?.write(`${cmd}`);
  }

  recieve(res: string) {
    console.log('recieved:');
    console.log(res);
  }

  exitHandler(data: string) {
    console.log('Exited');
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider using [`python-shell`](https://npmjs.com/package/python-shell).

Comment: And what specifically do you find not working? What's the problem?

Comment: I am not able to get the response back from the python program. The on "data" event is never firing. 
Also i do not want to use python-shell because i plan to make an executable out of the python program for production.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The fix is very simple actually. I just needed to add the `-u` flag while running the python process to make the output unbuffered and be available immediately.